# JDBC Sql Server table variables

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

is it possible to use table variables outside stored procedures?

In JDBC, I am trying to execute below queries one by one in below order, inside a transaction, should use same connection object.

1) `DECLARE @Tempt table (col1 int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)`
2) `insert into @Tempt select col from xtable where abc=1`

1st query executes fine means table variable created, but insert query fails with below error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Must declare the table variable "@Tempt".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:792)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:689)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
```

can some one please through somelight on this error?

Thanks

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258839(v=sql.80).aspx might help you

Comment: You have to run them with a **single** call to `execute()` passing one String with both statements separated with `;`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. can I construct something similar to anonymous pl/sql block in oracle in SQL Server?